# How to install Ubuntu Software Center on Parrot OS?

Tags: parrotsec

I m using the latest Parrot OS.
I would like to install the Ubuntu Software Center, so that I can install/uninstall my packages easily.

Is it possible to install the Ubuntu Software Center on Parrot OS?

Comment: Why not just use ubuntu instead? I think the same is true for Parrot as for Kali, so: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me?s=1|59.7813

Comment: Because Ubuntu is ugly.